# Add timestamp to Google Cloud Build log output

Tags: logging, google-cloud-platform, timestamp, continuous-integration, google-cloud-build

We are using [Cloud Build](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build) on [Google Cloud Platform](https://console.cloud.google.com/).

Is it possible to add a timestamp to every line of the log output?

Comment: hey @Harold L. Brown , I cannot clearly understand what you want to do here. Can you elaborate? do you mean like adding some kind of logging statement in Cloud Build? if you are concern about the build logs you can always check **stackdriver logging --> Cloud Build**. There you can find find every build step with their time stamps.

Comment: @MethkalKhalawi I want every log output statement to be prepended with a timestamp.
For example: Instead of `build finished` the statement should read `2020-04-08T07:46:35+00:00 build finished`.
So I can get a better guess about what takes how long in my build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot do this with Cloud Build directly but you can workaround by using [moreutils](http://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) package on linux:

```
gcloud builds submit --config cloudbuild.yaml | ts '[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]'
```

This will give you an output like:

```
[2020-04-08 10:53:53] starting build "50e00fbb-2224-46d4-b13a-6b15a9fbbe3c"
[2020-04-08 10:53:53]
[2020-04-08 10:53:53] FETCHSOURCE
[2020-04-08 10:53:53] Fetching storage object xxxxxxx
[2020-04-08 10:53:53] Copying xxxxxx
/ [1 files][  331.0 B/  331.0 B]                      
[2020-04-08 10:53:53] Operation completed over 1 objects/331.0 B.
[2020-04-08 10:53:53] BUILD
[2020-04-08 10:53:53] Starting Step #0
[2020-04-08 10:53:53] Step #0: Pulling image: ubuntu
[2020-04-08 10:53:53] Step #0: Using default tag: latest
[2020-04-08 10:53:53] Step #0: latest: Pulling from library/ubuntu
[2020-04-08 10:53:53] Step #0: Digest: xxxxxxx
[2020-04-08 10:53:53] Step #0: Status: Downloaded newer image for ubuntu:latest
[2020-04-08 10:53:53] Step #0: docker.io/library/ubuntu:latest
```

Answer (score 3):

The solution in @Methkal Khalawi's comment above works out of the box:  instead of looking at CloudBuild Logs within the CloudBuild tab of the GCP Console which look like this:
[image]

... open the Logging (Stack Driver) tab and select Cloud Build from the dropdown box.  This will show you the same logs you'd see in the Cloud Build tab, but now with timestamps, like this:
[image]